# 2-D array and pointer to 2-D array

Tags: c++11

```
int main()
{
int arr[][3]={{1,2},{3,4},{4,5}};
int (*p)[3];
p=arr;
cout<<sizeof(p)<<" "<<sizeof(*p);
return 0;
}
```

Above is my code,the output of this code is 4 12.So my doubt is what do the complier interpret p and *p as ? what they are actually pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P is a pointer, you probably have a 32-bit system, therefore  `sizeof(p)` returns 4.
Then you defined p as a pointer to an array of 3 ints, the sizeof int is 4, so the sizeof what it's pointing to, `sizeof(*p)` is 12.